# Predicting values from linear regression

Tags: regression, matlab, prediction, loss-functions

I've got a data set consisting of olympic years and the winning times for the womens 100m.

I can plot a line throught the data using matlab as such:

```
plot(x,w0 + w1*x, 'm-');
```

Which I believe is from the equation:

```
y=W0+w1x
```

Correct?

I also calculated the loss using this function:

```
function [w0,w1, S0, pointloss] = lsfit(x,t)

xmu = mean(x);
tmu = mean(t);

xt = x.*t;

xtmu = mean(xt);

x2mu = mean(x.*x);

w1 = (xtmu - xmu*tmu)/(x2mu-xmu^2);
w0 = tmu - w1*xmu;


loss = 0;
for n = 1:length(x)
    loss = loss + (t(n)-w0-w1*x(n))^2;
end

%average loss
S0 = loss/length(x);
```

So, assuming the above is correct, I have a few questions:

1. should the distance between the a given point and the line be equal to loss + (t(n)-w0-w1*x(n))^2 ?
2. Given the above, how do I predict the winning time for a given year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your expression for the loss, is actually the square of the residual, but yes, I think that is what you'll want to sum to see how well your regression matches the data.
2. For x(n)s that are outside of your dataset, you can use your linear estimate by simply plugging those years into your linear fit (i.e.  w0 - w1 x(n) ).  *However*, when you use a linear fit outside of your data your are extrapolating, which carries some danger of missing radical changes (equipment or technique) and possibly over-estimating the potential for infinite marginal improvements. For example, there will be some $x(n) = \frac{w0}{w1}$, for which your predicted t(n) will be 0.  This is obviously not possible.  So always be careful (i.e. don't bet the farm!) about trusting extrapolated predictions.